# UINavigationBar in UINavigationController rotations not acting as expected (items shifted up)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios-app-extension

I've been working on a set of iOS action extensions I seem to be having a problem with the way that the UINavigationBar is being displayed in the app if it is controlled by a UINavigationController.

The problem, in short is that the navigation bar gets shifted up when you rotate from portrait, to landscape, and back to portrait again. The problem is exacerbated if you rotate all the way around. I wish I could provide images, but I cannot given the rules of StackOverflow.

Regardless, this was tested using a only slightly modified Action App Extension (modified to lower target OS, silence a warning about the NSExtensionActiviationRule, etc), both with a UINavigationBar embedded in a UINavigationController and not embedded, just as a view in the ActionViewController. When not in an UINavigationController, the rotations look as expected, but retains a white patch around the status bar (and the navigation bar is slightly wider in the landscape orientation), but when put into a UINavigationController, the bar button items are shifted up.

This was tested pretty thoroughly in 8.2, and even now running the slightly modified app, it looks as one would expect. Does anyone know exactly going on here? Why does the button get shifted up when I use a UINavigationController in 8.3 and not 8.2? I can't seem to find any documentation on a change in 8.3 that would affect it, and no documentation that UINavigationController shouldn't be used in an Action Extension, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code, if you are interested, for the ViewController. Its not particularly enlightening, as it's basically what Apple gives you:

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class ActionViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Get the item[s] we're handling from the extension context.

    // For example, look for an image and place it into an image view.
    // Replace this with something appropriate for the type[s] your extension supports.
    var imageFound = false
    for item: AnyObject in self.extensionContext!.inputItems {
        let inputItem = item as! NSExtensionItem
        for provider: AnyObject in inputItem.attachments! {
            let itemProvider = provider as! NSItemProvider
            if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
                // This is an image. We'll load it, then place it in our image view.
                weak var weakImageView = self.imageView
                itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) in

                    let imageURL = url as! NSURL?;
                    if imageURL != nil {
                        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                            if let imageView = weakImageView {
                                let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL!.path!);

                                imageView.image = image;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })

                imageFound = true
                break
            }
        }

        if (imageFound) {
            // We only handle one image, so stop looking for more.
            break
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func done() {
    // Return any edited content to the host app.
    // This template doesn't do anything, so we just echo the passed in items.
    self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems(self.extensionContext!.inputItems, completionHandler: nil)
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!